# Android Xamarin, how to set nextfocusdown in EditText programmatically?

Tags: android, xamarin, android-edittext, focus

I have a loop adding views(with EditText) in linearlayout,
i want to set nextfocusdown for all edittext of this linear.
Someone known a way to do this automatically? Or setting nextfocusdown programmatically?

The code is like this...

```
var viewAux = layoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.FormEditTextItemView, null);
linearForm.AddView(viewAux, layoutParams);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

When i enter in dll of Android.Views.View
in propertie NextFocusDown, comment is saying that is only Get, but
works with Set too.